# Rounding and then Casting or vice versa

Tags: c#, math, double, decimal, rounding

1. `decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(valueAsDouble))`
2. `decimal value = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(valueAsDouble)`

Which is correct? What are the caveats?

Comment: In your case there's no difference, as `Round` will round to integers. Every double can safely be converted to an int. However if you were to round to let's say the first digit (e.g. `Math.Round(3.15)`), there may be differences, because 3.1 can't be safely converted to `double`, but to `decimal` for instance.